# How can I get this border bottom in nav on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve this border bottom on hover.
[image]

What I have so far is this:
[image]

And here's the code for what I have so far:

```
.navbar-nav li > a:after {
margin-top: .4rem;
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 2px;
background: var(--yellow);
transition: width .3s;
}
.navbar-nav li > a:hover::after {
width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post some stripped-down markup as well, so we can see a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: I think this will work for you `.navbar-nav li > a:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; }`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to create and position those two dots at the end of the lines:

**Update:** Now using an additional `::before` on the `<li>` element instead of `text-underline-offset` on the `<a>`, as Browsers seem to calculate the underline differently, resulting in misalignment of the line and the dots.

```css
body {
  background: #333
}

nav {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

nav li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li:hover::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid orange 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

nav li a:hover::before,
nav li a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
}

nav li a:hover:before {
  left: -3px;
}

nav li a:hover:after {
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you change `text-underline-offset` to `8px` to perfectly center the line?

Comment: For me in Chrome/Windows it's already centered perfectly, with `8px` it sits too low. Might be a browser/ppi issue?

Comment: Hmm, can be. `8px` works fine for Firefox/Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the issue in Firefox... Let me see if I can come up with something that looks fine in both

Comment: @Bickky Sahani - if this answer solved your question, please mark the answer as accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can mix-up pseudo element and `radial-gradient`

```css
body {
  background: #333
}

nav {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

nav li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav li a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 4%, red, red 4%, transparent 4%, transparent 75%), radial-gradient(circle at 96%, red, red 4%, transparent 4%, transparent 75%);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

nav li a:after {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

nav li a:hover:before,
nav li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the background image of the pseudo element by adding a radial gradient to the left and to the right:

```css
body {
  --yellow: gold; /* set to gold just so easier to see in the demo */
  }
.navbar-nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-nav li > a:after {
margin-top: .4rem;
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 4px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at left, var(--yellow) 0%, var(--yellow) 4px, transparent 4px),
  radial-gradient(circle at right, var(--yellow) 0%, var(--yellow) 4px, transparent 4px),
  linear-gradient(transparent 1px, var(--yellow) 1px, var(--yellow) 3px, transparent 3px, transparent);
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
transition: width .3s;
}
.navbar-nav li > a:hover::after {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a hre="">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The things that are at the beginning of the background image definition get drawn on top of the things that come after.